# While loop for split a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, split, append

I used this script. To split a big list.

```
var $bigList = $('.list-products'), group;
while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(4)').remove()).length) {
    $('<ul class="list-products"/>').append(group).appendTo('.box-products');
}
```

I have a problem with this script. I hope that you can help me.

When i run this script. The script do not remove the orginele ul. In the html there is a empty ul after running the script

And how can I make a div around it. I want a div with class product-container arround the ul lists.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Show the HTML you're *starting* with, and the HTML you'd like to have *afterwards*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $bigList = $('.list-products'), group;
while((group = $bigList.find('li:gt(3):lt(4)').remove()).length) {
    $('<ul class="list-products"/>').append(group).appendTo('.box-products');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vGSWN/1/)

Comment: Thanks this helps. But other question for the script. How can i put a div arround the ul's? When i doing this: 

$('<div class="container"><ul class="list-products"/>').append(group).appendTo('.box-products');

It is not working...

Comment: try `$('<ul class="list-products"/>').append(group).wrap('<div></div>').appendTo('.box-products')`